# What is the point of setting `output=False` in the PyAudio `open` method?

Tags: python, pyaudio

Below is a code example from [the PyAudio documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/), showing how to play a .wav file.
I understand that setting `output=False` in the `open` method prevents the file from playing, but what is the point of this? Is this reserved for debugging purpose?

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a wave file."""

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# play stream (3)
while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have input *and* output streams in `PyAudio`, setting `output = False` (which I think is the default anyway) just means it's not an output stream.

An output stream would be used (for example) to play an existing file to the sound subsystem (as per your code snippet).

An input stream may be used to pull info from the sound subsystem to record *to* a file.

I could see why someone may wonder why you would ever have both input *and* output set to false (and indeed, I think that's an error condition) but having `output` being false is fine provided `input` is true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer paxdiablo. I did not know there could be input streams in `PyAudio`!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR A stream can either be input, output, or both. At least either `output` or `input` must be `True`.

PyAudio states that the [`open` method of `PyAudio`](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio.open) opens a new stream:

> Open a new stream. See constructor for `Stream.__init__()` for parameter details.

When looking on [`Stream.__init__()`](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.__init__), we see that both input and output are default to false:

> input – Specifies whether this is an input stream. Defaults to False.

> output – Specifies whether this is an output stream. Defaults to False.

But there is a warning:

> Raises:
> ValueError – Neither input nor output are set True.

So stream can be either input (from computer sound system to a file) or output (from file to computer sound system) or both (callback).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `Stream` class constructor function: this clarifies that at least on of the output flags should be set to `True`.